# Dryer loses electrical power in the winter

Tags: wiring, dryer

For 3 years now my electric dryer loses the 220 current in the winter. It runs normally in the summer but gets weak in the winter. I have tried 4 different dryers and they all do the same thing. The receptacle is good and so is the circuit breaker.

Comment: Does your house have electric heating?  Can you tell which circuit breakers that and the dryer are on?

Comment: this sounds like some sort of wiring fault, voltage measurements made at the outlet can probably help locate the fault.

Comment: When you says “loses electrical power” it sounds like you mean it goes completely off or stops working, but later you use the words “gets weak” which sounds more like a brown-out or lowered voltage.  Could you clarify and tell us exactly what the symptoms are?

Answer (score 1):

Broken wire.

The 'inner' copper of the wire may be cracked. In summer metal expands and makes contact, in winter metal contracts and doesn't make contact anymore.

I suggest replacing the wire feeding the outlet.

Comment: Do they have 240 stab locks? Yuck.